# How can you tell if you're within a method call in Meteor?

Tags: meteor

I have this setup where when `collection.update()` is called from the client, a before-update hook gets triggered in the server (using `matb33:meteor-collection-hooks`). This trigger then uses `Meteor.user().someData` to get some data off the user. This works fine.

The problem is sometimes I need to update from the server, with no user in context. So I get a `Meteor.userId can only be invoked in method calls` error.

I'd like to know how to properly detect if the update hook is being run outside the context of a method call or publish function, when there is no user.

Comment: When you are in a Meteor method then `this.userId` will give you the userId of the current logged in user executing this method.

Comment: Okay, I found something. Meteor uses `DDP._CurrentInvocation.get()` to check whether  it is inside a method invocation (or similar...?). The problem is it seems to be undocumented and it might even have a different name in more current Meteor versions (I'm using an ancient meteor version). I'll be using it for now, but I'd appreciate some input from someone who knows anything else about this.

Comment: It may be easier to just conditionally execute your logic based on the existence of the user/session... otherwise you might need to use the some of the private/undocumented methods otherwise as you mentioned.